# "ReferenceError: ReduxObservable is not defined at jexomi.js:79:24"...can anyone help me fix this?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-observable

When I am trying to click Run with Js button in the [Using react example](http://jsbin.com/jexomi/edit?js,output) given in the online live examples of https://redux-observable.js.org/ site i am facing the following error:

```
"error"
"ReferenceError: ReduxObservable is not defined
    at jexomi.js:79:24"
```

Comment: Try this non-react example link - https://jsbin.com/vayoho/17/edit

Comment: Thanks for the example.....but any idea why the default example given in the link with react and redux is giving an error?

Comment: I didn't try but you can try changing the unpkg package for redux-observable